# Erro na string ao conectar banco de dados sql server remotamente

Tags: sql, string, servidor, conexão

Sou iniciante em C# e estou tentando conectar remotamente minha aplicação com um banco SQL Server que está em outro PC... Neste PC já foi configurado a porta TCP/IP seguindo este modelo do link: http://www.sqlfromhell.com/habilitando-a-conexao-remota-no-sql-server/

Se tento conectar pelo SQL Management Studio com o IP do PC, FUNCIONA!

Porém na minha aplicação C# sempre retorna o erro: "*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar Servidor/Instância Especificada)'*"

Segue como tenho estruturado minha conexão:

**App.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Sistema.Properties.Settings.SistemaConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.xxx,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=meusistema;User ID=sa;Password=********" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="*************" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.11.12.0" newVersion="1.11.12.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Classe de Conexão:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sistema
{
    class Conexao
    {
        public Conexao()
        {
        }
        public static SqlConnection Conectar()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=xxx.xxx.x.xxx\\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Sistema;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

                return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que você está utilizando duas strings de conexão diferentes? No app.config tem uma e na classe de conexão tem outra

Comment: No app.config monto a string de conexão com senha e tudo mais... na classe de conexão uso para instanciar a conexão... funciona (quando eu tinha o banco de dados sql server instalado no mesmo PC em que estou desenvolvendo o programa). Porém se tiver alguma ideia melhor de como posso estruturar esta conexão é bem vinda!

Comment: Normalmente usa a string de conexão do app.config lá! O app.config deve centralizar as configurações do seu projeto.